# if condition used to display status of sql query

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, if-statement

I am developing a student registration project on java. i want to display a message as "deleted successfully" when the delete all query execute and "not deleted message" if there are no records to delete.

How can I do this with an `if-else` condition, I have already done but it display no records to delete even there are.  code executes fine, only the message get the problem

Answer (score 0):

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)) states `executeUpdate()` returns either :

- the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements
- `0` for SQL statements that return nothing.

In your case, you could check if the returned value is superior to `0`.

```
if(st.executeUpdate(query) > 0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "All Records Deleted     
Successfully ");
       }
}
else{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No records to delete ");
}
```

Comment: when i use that it says no records to delete either.

Comment: it means that no row was deleted. Have you checked that you have data inside the table before executing this code ?

Comment: yes there is a jtable, displaying all information, everything works fine, but only getting wrong msg.

Comment: no matter if there are data or not, always getting no records to delete msg, but if there is data it will be delete successfully

Comment: if i include this to 0, mean if((st.executeUpdate(query))==0) it will display All Records Deleted     
Successfully. even if ther is no data. but it delete all data if exist

Comment: a `JTable` is a graphical component. It is not the `student` table of your database. I referred to the `student` table in your MySQL database.

Comment: it is same as whats happening in the jtable.